# How to filter data from dataframe with comparison operator between boolean and string data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am working on a data set with below types of data:

```
gender,year,Horror,Fiction,Comedy,words
m,  1980,   F,  F,  T,  abc def
m,  1980,   F,  T,  F,  gh hjjtt kl[pom
f,  1990,   F,  F,  T,  ghj khgr kll
f,  1970,   T,  F,  F,  or jtu jajd
f,  2000,   F,  F,  T,  rreun jfmn
f,  2010,   T,  F,  F,  jhhkjn jlkjan
```

So here I have boolean values for the columns `Horror`, `Fiction`, and `Comedy`.

I want to count the number of males where the column `Horror == True`

I tried all the below code but it all is giving an error:

```
Male_data = data[data.gender == 'm' & data.Horror == True]
```

```
Male_data = data[data['gender'] == 'm' & data['Horror'] == True]
```

```
Male_data = data[data['gender'] == 'm'] & data[data['Horror'] == True]
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: add some parentheses around your first 2 attempts.  & normally has a pretty high order of ptecedence

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Male_data = data[(data.gender == 'm') & (data.Horror == True)]
```

Or:

```
Male_data = data[data.gender.eq('m') & data.Horror.eq(True)]
```

`&` has a higher priority than `==`, so you need to wrap the `==` conditions in parentheses to override the priority rules and make the `==` operations evaluate first.